# How to display FullHD images?

Tags: android, image, hdmi

I am writing a simple application displaying 1080p images full screen. My problem is when I start application the resolution changes to 1280x720 (values returned by getDisplayMetrics) and I loose important for me details of images. Is there a way to set resolution to 1920x1080 or to prevent scaling to 720p?

I am using a Measy U1A smart tv dongle connected via HDMI to a 23" LG monitor. Android version is 4.0.4 and in display settings 1920x1080 60Hz is set. The pictures are 1920x1080 bmp files stored in "drawable-xhdpi" folder and I display them as background images using setBackgroundResource.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the image in a folder named

`drawable-nodpi`

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. Result is the same - display is scaled to 1280x720.